# detect a color within an area near my cursor

Tags: java

I want to be able to detect a color within a square, or circular area (whichever is easier) NEAR my mouse pointer. My example below works but the mouse has to be directly on the color to detect it.
In my example, I simply used the MS Paint standard red, but I am looking to detect specific colors in a gradient area when my cursor is let's say 100 pixels above, below, to the left or right of the target color, it will detect it. I think I need to loop within a range of pixels around my cursor's current location, but I can't seem to get it.
Adding to my code would really help as I've already spent too much time on this site and others trying out ideas.

### Thanks!

```
import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.MouseInfo;

import java.awt.Point;

import java.awt.PointerInfo;

import java.awt.Robot;

public class DetectRed {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

PointerInfo pointer;

pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();

Point coord = pointer.getLocation();

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(2000);

        while(true)
        {
            //print coords
            coord = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            System.out.println("Coord = " + coord);

            //print colors
            Color color = robot.getPixelColor((int)coord.getX(), (int)coord.getY());
            System.out.println("Color = " + color);

            if(color.getRed() == 237 && color.getGreen() == 28 && color.getBlue() == 36)
            {
                System.out.println("RED(237,28,36) FOUND");
            }

            System.out.println(); //blank line separator

            robot.delay(500); //use shorter delay to scan faster...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the color detection in a for loop to scan over a neighborhood:

```
for (int x = (int)coord.getX()-window; x <= (int)coord.getX()+window; ++x) {
  for (int y = (int)coord.getY()-window; y <= (int)coord.getY()+window; ++y) {
    Color color = robot.getPixelColor(x, y);
    // Check if it matches.
  }
}
```

You might want to do some bounds checking to ensure that `x-window` and `x+window` (and similarly for y) are within the bounds of your rectangle. And, of course, choose `window` to your particular requirements.